# Django TemplateDoesNotExist at /rango/

Tags: django, django-templates

I've seen this question asked before, but I'm already using the newer TEMPLATES data structure which is the common solution.

From the tango with django book, I'm currently on unit 4.  When I run my program with `python manage.py runserver`

I receive the following error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /rango/

rango/index.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

rango/index.html
```

Here is the relevant code in my `~/Workspace/wad2/tango_with_django_project/setings.py` file:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tango_with_django_project', 'templates')
.
.
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
.
.
```

Also, here is the relevant code in my `~/Workspace/wad2/rango/views.py` file:

```
def index(request):
    context_dict = {'boldmessage': "Crunchy, creamy, cookie, candy, cupcake!"}

    return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)
```

Also, I cannot solve this problem with a direct path since I am trying to stick to the tutorial with dynamic pahs.  Lastly, my template is located at `~/Workspace/wad2/tango_with_django_project/templates/rango/index.html`

Comment: Try adding `APP_DIRS: True` to your template dict ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#app-dirs))

Comment: @Sayse, I already have that.  I'll edit my question to include it.

Comment: Wait, your error says you're using Django 1.5.1?..

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov: I've included the structure at the end of my question.

Comment: Then don't use the new templates setting, use the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` or whichever 1.5.1 uses or upgrade to a supported version of django.

Comment: @Sayse Hmm, the tutorial I'm following should be 1.9 and above.  This may be the issue.. EDIT:  Yes, that solved the problem with `pip install django==1.10.5`

Comment: @Sayse try then to change Django version, because the settings for templates in Django 1.5 had different format

Comment: try with `TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tango_with_django_project/templates')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by updating my django version with:

`pip install django==1.10.5`